# How to link one Viewcontroller to another

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I have a `ViewController` and inside that `Viewcontroller`, I have to call another `ViewController`.I am unable to make my other `viewcontroller` work .The issue is that the inside `ViewController` is a image field and the outside `ViewController` has some buttons.when a user clicks on any button,the functions will run on inside `ViewController` and the data will be outputted from outside `ViewController`.But I am getting errors in my code. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please edit your questions and add some code with errors?

Comment: Will you plz put some code to understand what exactly you want?

Comment: Well my code for first viewcontroller:-(void)buttonpressed
{
    NSString *allElements = [myarray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSLog(@"%@", allElements);
}

Comment: My code fr 2nd viewcontroller2- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 
 mouseSwiped = NO;
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 
 if ([touch tapCount] == 4) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
 }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"touchbegan Self.view.frame.height = %f and width = %f ", self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width);    
        lastPoint = [touch locationInView:drawImage];
        Well..I have to print my image draw points from viewcontroller 2 to viewcontroller 1

Answer (score 0):

According to my opinion,

Please change your code and take one UIView inside the ViewController and set its IBOutlet and add this view to your ViewController....

And Take all button and anyother Controls inside your ViewController and see what happens...

On button tap event, make your code working for UIView changes..

Hope It will works...

Comment: Well Marvin I tried the way you asked me do before and it worked fine.But I am not getting the desired output it was used to be.So,I decided to use two viewcontroller and place my imageview inside second viewcontroller,call that viewcontroller from first viewcontroller .But I am unable to link them.CAn you or anyone help me.I am really stuck .